# Handle error_level variable in batch FOR command

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set JAVA_HOME=C:\java
set "CLASSPATH=C:\iDQS\runtime\bin\\..\lib\;"


for /f "delims=" %%i in (%~dp0\plan_list_dev.txt) do (

call C:\iDQS\runtime\bin\runcif -runtimeConfig "%~dp0\..\..\runtimeCfg.xml" -statusFile "%~dp0\..\..\planstatusfile\new_status_file_%%i.txt" "%~dp0\%%i.plan" >> "%~dp0\2_new_log_%%i.txt"

if !errorlevel! == 0 goto :picknextplan
    echo !errorlevel!.1
    echo "Error at %%i loop"
exit -99

:picknextplan
echo %~dp0%%i
)


if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :next
echo "Errors encountered during plan execution.  Exited with status: %errorlevel%"
EXIT -99 
goto :endofscript

:next
echo "Ending Plan execution"

:endofscript

EXIT
```

plan_list_dev.txt contains list of argument as plan name e.g.

clean_data
load_data

it runs only first argument "clean_data" and keep exiting ...
i want both should run ..only exit if any fails or exit with non zero error_level.

Can any one help me out on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if !errorlevel! NEQ 0 (
    echo !errorlevel!.1
    echo "Error at %%i loop"
exit -99)

echo %~dp0%%i
```

Labels should not be used within a `code block` (parenthesised code sequence)

```
EXIT -99 
goto :endofscript
```

This sequence is illogical. The `exit` statement terminates the process, so the `goto` will never be executed.

The `:` is not required in a `goto`.

Comment: N also thanks for editing ...i m new ..so i didn't know how to use it properly ....i appreciate your support